# get and send data in String[] Array using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
 int i = 0;
 String[] pnumbers = new String[3];
 String[] pqtys = new String[3];

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

 String pnumber = request.getParameter("pnumber");
 DAO dao = new DAO();
 Product p = dao.checkProduct(pnumber);
 String qunty = request.getParameter("pqty");

  while (i < 3) {
  pnumbers[i] = p.getNumber();
  pqtys[i] = p.getQty();
  i++;
  }
request.setAttribute("pnum" pnumbers);
}
```

I need to add 3 items coming by webpage in to this array. but ones you can add one item

```
<td>
<input type="text" name="pnumber" value="" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="pqty" value="" />
</td>
```

i need to add only 3 items to array after adding those 3 i need to get that values again to same page please help?

Comment: you html code doesn't uses looping for displaying the 3 products and quantity. Can you please elaborate more on your query?

Answer (score 0):

Once you set attribute in you Servlet like you have done.

```
request.setAttribute("pnum" pnumbers);
```

Forward control from Servlet to required JSP and You can access it in your JSP using

`request.getAttribute(paramName)`

Hint:

```
if(request.getAttribute("pnum")!=null){
    String []strArray = (String []) request.getAttribute("pnum");
    for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
         out.println(strArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Print the values at your required point.